# Azure Java SDK - how to know when a container is really deleted

Tags: java, azure, sdk, containers

I need to remove all blobs from a container. I thought the easy way to do this would be to delete and re-create the container. Not so much...

Here is the code that waits:

```
while (saClient.getContainerReference(myContainerName.exists()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.interrupted();
        System.out.println("<: interrupted");
        return;
    }
}
```

When I come out of that loop, I try to re-create the container and get the exception:

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified container is being deleted. Try operation later.
```

I can re-code to delete each blob, but am curious about this interface behavior. I might have the same problem with each blob not really being deleted.

I am using these library versions:

```
com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:4.2.0
com.microsoft.azure:azure:1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, there's no API call that you can make which will tell you that a container is actually deleted as the deletion process is an asynchronous process.

From the documentation [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-container#remarks):

> When a container is deleted, a container with the same name cannot be
>   created for at least 30 seconds; the container may not be available
>   for more than 30 seconds if the service is still processing the
>   request. While the container is being deleted, attempts to create a
>   container of the same name will fail with status code 409 (Conflict),
>   with the service returning additional error information indicating
>   that the container is being deleted. All other operations, including
>   operations on any blobs under the container, will fail with status
>   code 404 (Not Found) while the container is being deleted.

What you would need to do is keep on retrying creating a blob container. If the operation fails with status code 409 and error code `ContainerBeingDeleted`, that means the container is still being deleted. You could retry the operation after waiting for some time.

I would still recommend delete container approach over deleting each blob in the container as delete container is a single operation while to delete all blobs you will have to make as many operations as there are blobs in that container.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to remember to check the REST API documentation in the future. The Java SDK docs are not as specific.